# Mapping array inside async function causes error

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, dictionary

Hello i have array of objects validation inside my async function (router.post()) and i need to map it before validating and this is how I do it

```
ingredients.map(({ingredient,quantity})=>{
   if(ingredient.trim().length < 1 || quantity.length < 1){
     return res.status(409).send({
       message: ''
     })
   }
})
```

and after this i send 200 status code to client side (ReactJS) but it causes error

> Can't set headers after they are sent

i do not know what is problem with this.

before this block of code i have only if statements to validate other inputs and when i commented this block of code the if statements worked. So what is problem with this?

P.S: I stringified array before sending the server and then parsed of course

EDIT: it does not causes errors when everything is ok and ingredient or quanitity is not empty

Comment: Well, don't call `res.status()` or `res.send()` in a loop. Send a response exactly once. What data do you want to put in the response message?

Comment: alright but only res.send() will be deprecated soon and what then?

Comment: in express 5x it will not be accepted anymore

Comment: Sure you should use both `status` and `send`, but you should use *neither* of them in a loop.

Comment: I want to put alert message in response to make sure user filled input

Comment: so what should i do

Comment: Check your `ingredients` array whether there is any error (e.g. using `every`, not `map`). Then afterwards, when there was one (or more) errors in the data, send your 409 response. Else, if there was no error, send your other response.

Comment: thank you! i think thats proper answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue occurs because `res.send` is being called multiple times.

If your intention is to respond with `409` status code if at least one of ingredients is invalid, you can check if there is at least one invalid item and respond with `409` if it's there:

```
const hasInvalidIngredient = ingredients.some(
  ({ingredient,quantity}) => ingredient.trim().length == 0 || quantity.length == 0
)

if (hasInvalidIngredient) {
  return res.status(409).send({
    message: ''
  })
}
```

Comment: I mean it does not validate

Comment: @iLiA Can you please provide an example of `ingredients` array when the validation does not work while it should?

Comment: [{ingredient: 'foo', quantity: '1'}, {ingredient: 'bar', quantity: '2'}]

Comment: Since `quantity` is a string you can parse it to a number and check correspondingly `parseInt(quantity) < 1`. I have updated the answer

Comment: no need to parse it does not have to be number it can be 1g for example or 2kg

Comment: I see, so which quantity value should be considered invalid?

Comment: empty value of ingredient and quantity

Comment: Well, if an item is invalid if either `ingredient` or `quantity` is an empty string then condition `!ingredient.trim() || !quantity.trim()` should work. If an item is invalid when both properties are empty string then condition `!ingredient.trim() && !quantity.trim()` should do the trick. If neither works then the issue may be elsewhere.